# jupyter notebooks - voila not able to use ipython widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, voila

I am trying to use voila to turn my Jupyter notebook into an interactive webpage (with the end goal of putting it on Github and using it in Binder). Voila seems to work fine when I don't try to display any IPython widgets, but as soon as try to display some, I get a Javascript error saying:

```
Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
Error: Module @jupyter-widgets/controls, version ^1.5.0 is not registered, however,         2.0.0 is
    at tn.loadClass (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:117212)
    at tn.loadClass (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:472:57590)
    at tn.loadModelClass (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:114982)
    at tn._make_model (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:111789)
    at tn.new_model (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:109386)
    at http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:110660
    at Array.map ()
    at tn._loadFromKernel (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:458:110550)
    at async tn.build_widgets (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/voila.js?v=8db1cadbfba43a6dfc2d64128318e696bcb26b1783db1b991faf7404d438cd53200b6c434c4897064c090b68aa1151cd96c6dab50c3e138553365e6b30889172:472:56804)
    at async init (http://localhost:8812/voila/templates/lab/static/main.js?v=07cc494763c3dcb3b604da7aa291ed361b8b163d9cb33c4bc3a66304c18e1dc5bfcf8c6101b6b6426ab36762a01a8568e9f3bf0c7ba6588cd61eab538b95e34a:63:13)
```

It doesn't seem to be a problem with my code, as I tried it on the [demo voila code](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila/tree/main/notebooks) and still got the error, only when I try to display widgets.

My assumption is that it is a problem with packages I have downloaded, so I already tried making new anaconda environments, updating packages, etc.

I tried using voila to turn my Jupyter notebook with widgets into an interactive web page, but I get Javascript errors when using widgets.

Comment: I'm not following how, "It doesn't seem to be a problem with my code, as I tried it on the demo voila code and still got the error, only when I try to display widgets," equates to your title: "voila not able to use ipython widgets"? Voila is able to use ipywidgets. On the other hand, I'm not sure if your effort to work this out on your local computer is a good use of your time if your goal, as stated, is to use Voila via MyBinder? It already works in sessions from there. You can use that to work out your code perhaps?

Comment: @Wayne I should have worded my title better, you're right. I did not mean to imply that voila cannot handle widgets, just that whenever I use widgets I got the error. Thanks for the suggestion about not worrying about how it works on my local machine, it didn't even occur to me that I could just use binder to figure it out.

Comment: Let me know if you need help customizing your environment via your repo for use on MyBinder. Plus often how to launch correctly to the proper interface trips up people. For developing, I suggest using JupyterLab and then adjusting to launch diretly into Voila later. JupyterLab is especially nice for developing with Voila and MyBinder because of the button that launches a panel on the side with the Voila rendering.  Keep in mind saving your notebook and versions back to your local machine often because of the temporary nature of the sessions.

Comment: Actually, if you could help me out, that would be great. I'm still stuck on this a week later, and getting MyBinder to work isn't my main focus (I'm just doing this to follow along in a textbook), so it's very frustrating. Is there any way I can message you with images for help, or should I just open a new question?

Comment: Probably easiest is to direct message me over at the [Jupyter Community Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). That allows posting code and images, I believe. If not, you could probably at least link to a private gist. My username is fomightez there. You could direct message me or open an public post. I suspect it is just working out URLs/configurations so probably direct message is fine because already plenty of advice on coordinating myBinder and Voila there.

Comment: Also, see several working examples using MyBinder [here](https://github.com/fomightez/communication_voila/tree/master#readme).